# How to add popup on waypoints markers including start and end using leaflet routing machine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am trying to put the popup when you click on the waypoint or even from start and end points on the route. So in simple words if you have point A, B and C and I need popup on all those A, B and c Markers.

I have tried this but so far I have manage on only one marker and not the all so let me know how we can do this.......

Here is my code:

```
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo PLUGINS_DIR;?>leaflet_routing_machine/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo PLUGINS_DIR;?>leaflet_control_geocoder/Control.Geocoder.js"></script>

    <script>

    var map = L.map('mapid').setView([-36.85625, 174.76141], 5);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all//{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>',

    id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(map);

var geocoder = L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(),
    routeControl = L.Routing.control({
    geocoder: geocoder,
  routeWhileDragging: false,
}).addTo(map),
    waypoints = [];

geocoder.geocode('94 Dominion Road, Mount Eden Auckland', function(a, b) {
    // depending on geocoder results may be either in a or b 
   // console.log(a);
    // choose the best result here. probably the first one in array
    var point = a[0];
    // create waypoint object
    var wpt = L.Routing.waypoint(L.latLng(point.center.lat, point.center.lng), point.name)
    waypoints.push(wpt);
  routeControl.setWaypoints(waypoints);

  var marker_first = L.marker([point.center.lat, point.center.lng], {
      draggable: false
    }).addTo(map);
    marker_first.bindPopup('<strong>Journey Start:</strong>94 Dominion Road, Mount Eden Auckland');
})

geocoder.geocode('5 Flower Street, Eden Terrace, Auckland', function(a, b) {
    // depending on geocoder results may be either in a or b 
    //console.log(a);
    // choose the best result here. probably the first one in array
    var point = a[0];
    // create waypoint object
    var wpt = L.Routing.waypoint(L.latLng(point.center.lat, point.center.lng), point.name)
    waypoints.push(wpt);

  routeControl.setWaypoints(waypoints);
  var marker_second = L.marker([point.center.lat, point.center.lng], {
      draggable: false
    }).addTo(map);
    marker_second.bindPopup('<strong>Waypoint:</strong>5 Flower Street, Eden Terrace, Auckland');
/*  var popup = L.popup()
   .setLatLng(L.latLng(point.center.lat, point.center.lng))
    .setContent('<p>Hello world!<br />This is a nice popup.</p>')
    .addTo(map);*/
}) 


geocoder.geocode('280 Queen Street, Auckland 1010', function(a, b) {
    // depending on geocoder results may be either in a or b 
    //console.log(a);
    // choose the best result here. probably the first one in array
    var point = a[0];
    // create waypoint object
    var wpt = L.Routing.waypoint(L.latLng(point.center.lat, point.center.lng), point.name)
    waypoints.push(wpt);
  routeControl.setWaypoints(waypoints);
  var marker_third = L.marker([point.center.lat, point.center.lng], {
      draggable: false
    }).addTo(map);
    marker_third.bindPopup('<strong>End Journey:</strong>280 Queen Street, Auckland 1010');

})
//.on('click', function(e) { console.log("hello"); });
    </script>
```

Any running code on fiddle would be very helpful but if you can edit my code and make it work even that's help me a lot. Thank you so much in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var message = ["Custom <strong>mesage1</strong>","Custom <strong>message2</strong>","Custom <strong>mesasge3</strong>"];
    var geocoder = L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(),
    routeControl = L.Routing.control({
     plan: L.Routing.plan(waypoints, {
                createMarker: function(i, wp) {
                    if(waypoints[0]) {
                        return L.marker(wp.latLng, {
                        draggable: false
                    }).bindPopup(message[i]).openPopup();

                    }

                },
    geocoder: geocoder,
  routeWhileDragging: false
  })
}).addTo(map),
    waypoints = [];
```

So basically, I got this answer from one of the genius person on the stack and only point of doing this is so that anyone else can resolve if they come across to this issue......haha:)